# how to make my highcharts reverse

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, graph, highcharts

i want to draw a graph using highcharts.
the question is, why my x axis and y axis reverse. i'm using json for my series.
i'm stuck. this how look like
[this is how my program works. i want to reverse it but i dont know what to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUK0E.png)

heres the code

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(function () {
         Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false,
            
        },
        lang: {
          decimalPoint: ',',
          thousandsSep: '.'
        }
    });
      
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("dataline.php", function(json) {
        
          chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
              renderTo: 'mygraph',
              type: 'bar'
              
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Debet dan Kredit'
              
            },
            subtitle: {
              text: '2017'
            
            },
            xAxis: {
              categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
              title:{
                text: 'Total (Rp)'
              }
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: {
                text: 'Bulan'
              },
              plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
              }]
            },

            tooltip: {
              //fungsi tooltip, ini opsional, kegunaan dari fungsi ini 
              //akan menampikan data di titik tertentu di grafik saat mouseover
              formatter: function() {
                  return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                  this.x +': Rp. '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y,1,',','.');
                  
              },
            },
            legend: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              align: 'right',
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              x: -10,
              y: 120,
              borderWidth: 0
            },
            //series adalah data yang akan dibuatkan grafiknya, diisi data
            series: json
          });
        });
      
      });
      
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Grafik Seluruh Total Debet dan Kredit</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id ="mygraph"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for my  dataline.php

```html
<?php
include "connection.php";
session_start();
$level = $_SESSION['level'];
$toko  =$_SESSION['id_toko'];
//Data untuk debet 

if($level =='manajer' || $level=='bendahara'){
 $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select month(tanggal), sum(debet) as tot from jurnalumum_detail  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(jurnalumum_detail.tanggal,'%m') ORDER BY month(tanggal) desc LIMIT 1;");
}else if ($level=='owner'){
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select month(tanggal), sum(debet) as tot from jurnalumum_detail GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(jurnalumum_detail.tanggal,'%m') ORDER BY month(tanggal) desc LIMIT 1;");}
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Debet';
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $lastmonth = $row['month(tanggal)'];
    }
    for($i = 1 ; $i <= $lastmonth ; $i++){
     if($level =='manajer' || $level=='bendahara'){
      $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select month(tanggal), sum(debet) as tot from jurnalumum_detail where month(tanggal) = '$i' AND id_toko='$toko' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(jurnalumum_detail.tanggal,'%m') ;");
     }else if($level=='owner'){
        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select month(tanggal), sum(debet) as tot from jurnalumum_detail where month(tanggal) = '$i' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(jurnalumum_detail.tanggal,'%m') ;"); }
        $jumlah = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($jumlah == 0){
         $rows['data'][] = 0;
    }else{
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $row;
        $rows['data'][] = $row['tot'];
    }   
    }
}


//Data untuk kredit
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select month(tanggal), sum(kredit) as tot from jurnalumum_detail GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(jurnalumum_detail.tanggal,'%m') ORDER BY month(tanggal) desc LIMIT 1;");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Kredit';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $lastmonth = $row['month(tanggal)'];
    }
    for($i = 1 ; $i <= $lastmonth ; $i++){
  if($level=='manajer' || $level=='bendahara'){
        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select month(tanggal), sum(kredit) as tot from jurnalumum_detail where month(tanggal) = '$i' AND id_toko = '$toko' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(jurnalumum_detail.tanggal,'%m') ;");}
        $jumlah = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($jumlah == 0){
         $rows1['data'][] = 0;
    }else{
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $row;
        
        $rows1['data'][] =  $row['tot'];
    }   
    }
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



?>
```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELPING! I REALLY NEED THIS

Comment: Could you paste your output JSON here?

Comment: @SebastianBochan here is my output json

Comment: @SebastianBochan [{"name":"Debet","data":[0,0,0,66699,6666,8000]},{"name":"Kredit","data":[0,0,0,7799,0,0]}]

Comment: How about array_reverse($result, true); ? If it does not work you can reverse series in the javascript. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eygLtcrn/

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your array before decoding it JSON

```
$data = array_reverse($result);
echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 2 to be boolean, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugasakhir6\dataline.php on line 57

Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 2 to be boolean, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugasakhir6\dataline.php on line 58
[]

Comment: Use array_reverse($result, true); -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php